# Not All Attributes Displaying in Magento Frontend Attribute Table

Tags: magento

I have products with 20+ attributes (mostly technical specifications) populated in the backend of a Magento EE 1.12 store.

Problem is, on the frontend, only the first handful of specs are displayed.

If I move attributes up and down in the "Manage Attribute Sets," I can get ones further down the list to display on the frontend, at the expense of other attributes that get moved down the list.

(Setting up different attributes in different groups did not solve the problem.)

All of the attributes are Yes for "Visible on Product View Page on Front-end."

Here's an example: http://www.topbulb.com/mh100w-c-u-ed28-ps-bulb-100w-pulse-start-metal-halide-coated-mogul-base

Under the last spec in the table is another populated attribute. It's not showing in the code, but it should be.

How can I get Magento to display all of the specs?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this one this way.

Original code in template/catalog/product/view.phtml

```
<?php foreach ($_helperCategorylist->getProductAttributes($_product,22) as $_attributeName => $_attributeValue): ?>
```

I upped the $_product,22 to $_product,42 and the rest of the attributes showed up on the frontend.